# Streamwriter writes different then Console.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have a streamwriter who writes the data from a process stream in to a log file. When I show the output with `Console.WriteLine()` the Result looks like:

```
SW DATA = Sep 23, 2016 9:40:37 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
SW DATA = INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP3-connect
SW DATA = Sep 23, 2016 9:40:38 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
SW DATA = INFO: Server didn't accept the handshake: Unknown protocol:Protocol:JNLP3-connect
SW DATA = Sep 23, 2016 9:40:38 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
SW DATA = INFO: Connecting to Machine:51136
SW DATA = Sep 23, 2016 9:40:38 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
SW DATA = INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP2-connect
SW DATA = Sep 23, 2016 9:40:38 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
SW DATA = INFO: Connected
```

But when I open the Textfile, it looks like:

```
INFO: Connected
:38 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
LP3-connect
6231dd with ID 
ad is recommended.
```

My Code is:

```
    static void ShowOutput(string data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\LogFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            Console.WriteLine("SW DATA = " + data);
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                w.WriteLine(data);
                w.Flush();
            }
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

It looks like the writer only writes the end of every Line.

The Data Comes from a console process similar to this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4665/Launching-a-process-and-displaying-its-standard-ou

My Question is:

How can I prevent this ?

Comment: Why not ```File.AppendAllText``` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It looks like the writer only writes the end of every Line.

This is because you re-open the file every time, overwriting the previous content. You either need to keep the file open between calls to `ShowOutput`, or open it in `Append` mode.

The mixed-up content in the file is because it only overwrites the beginning of the file (doesn't truncate it), so if you write a log entry shorter than the previous ones, the end of the the previous text remains.

Comment: OK, but why this happens? I know, that this way is slow and not optimal, but it should work...

Comment: Because when you open the file again, the position that the stream will write to is at position 0, every time. Every line you write to the file is written from the start of the file. You essentially overwrite the start of the previous line, and if the new line is shorter you leave bits and pieces of the previous line dangling. If you want to append the new line at the end you actually have to tell .NET to open the file for appending.

Comment: OK, now I see, that author is opening file for writing, not appending... Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Working Mode Append has fixed the problem !